Angular - Display labels without waiting for their value
My component display users'attributes (name, email, ...).
I would like to display labels without waiting for their value. I found a solution but I don't like it because I repeat <span *ngIf="user">.
With the following example I immediately display
name: 
email:
...

and 5s later
name:Nicolas 
email:nicolas@ggg.fr
...

user.component.html :
<div>
    name : <span *ngIf="user">{{ user.name }}</span> <br/>
    email : <span *ngIf="user">{{ user.email }}</span> <br/>
    ...
</div>

user.component.ts
export class UserComponent {
  user?: User;

  constructor(private userService: UserapiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // getUser1() calls an API and lasts 5s for example
    this.userService.getUser1().subscribe(user1 => this.user = user1);
  }
}

I don't want the following code because the whole  would be displayed 5s later
<div *ngIf="user">
    name : {{ user.name }} <br/>
    email : {{ user.email }}<br/>
    ...
</div>

What is the best solution to display labels without waiting for their value ?
Thanks for your help,
Nicolas

Using the Safe Navigation Operator (?.):
This operator allows you to access properties on potentially null or undefined objects without causing errors.
<div>
  name: {{ user?.name }} <br/>
  email: {{ user?.email }} <br/>
  ...
</div>

